# When I import css file Vue generates this type of style tag in the head section

Tags: css

I have created a simple project in Vue.
When I import css file Vue generates this type of style tag in the head section.
I don't want it.
Is there any other way to import CSS?

I have tried this way to import in main.ts file.

// //CUSTOM THEME
import "@/assets/css/style.scss";

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put your own css make sure it has the "scoped" tag so that **`<style scoped>`** also works with **`<style module>`**